# Replace multiple month-strings to month-ints

Tags: string, go, replace

I am working with strings such as the below:

`"JAN-5,Feb,6 dec=900"`

I'm looking to replace the Month strings with their respective month int value. So the above would equate to:

`"1-5,2,6 12=900"`

I understand that using a case-insensitive regex may be the way to go, however I've only seen examples of how to apply this to one month at a time, which seems inefficient, for example:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)jan`)
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("JAN-5,Feb,6 dec=900", "1"))
```

Is there an easier way to do this rather than apply 12 different regex tests to the string?

Comment: Do you need to keep rest of the string "case-intact"? Is it OK if other parts of the string become lower-cased?

Comment: ` seems inefficient` don't suppose perf issue, mesure it. For very high perf you can write your own lexer/parser but this is only when you really need it. Regexp can bring lot of issue like ReDos attack. A simple `ReplaceAll` with normalize string can do the job

Comment: @icza the case-intact shouldn't be an issue as the only alphabetical chars will be month strings, therefore ultimately replaced with their int equivalent. Any other chars in the string will be special chars, such as ",=/" etc

Comment: @Ôrel it's possible to use a `ReplaceAll` once? or it's a case of having 12 ReplaceAll's to parse each possible option..?

Comment: You might be able to make use of; https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReplacer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lower the string using [`strings.ToLower()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ToLower) and then you may use a single [`strings.Replacer`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replacer) with the 12 months which does all possible replaces in one "step":

```
var r = strings.NewReplacer(
    "jan", "1",
    "feb", "2",
    "mar", "3",
    "apr", "4",
    "may", "5",
    "jun", "6",
    "jul", "7",
    "aug", "8",
    "sep", "9",
    "oct", "10",
    "nov", "11",
    "dec", "12",
)

func main() {
    s := "JAN-5,Feb,6 dec=900"

    s2 := r.Replace(strings.ToLower(s))

    fmt.Println(s2)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EWZT0tSKRH7)):

```
1-5,2,6 12=900
```

Comment: This is amazing. I'd never heard of `strings.NewReplacer` and this works perfectly!